# About an approximation of a continuous function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let \Omega be a bounded domain in $R^{n}$ and $u$ be a continuous function on $\overline{\Omega}$. For any $\epsilon>0$, we define an approximation function $u^{\epsilon}$ as $$u^{\epsilon}(x):=\max\limits_{\bar{B}_{\epsilon}(x)\cap\overline{\Omega}}\{u(y)+(\epsilon^{2}-|x-y|^{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}\},\quad\forall x\in\overline{\Omega}.$$

How to prove that $u^{\epsilon}$ is continuous on $\overline{\Omega}$ and $u^{\epsilon}\downarrow u$ as $\epsilon\downarrow0$.

This is a modified approximation of jensen i think and it is very useful in the theory of viscosity solution.

Comment: Is $B_\epsilon(x)$ a closed ball?

Comment: yes  it is closed

Answer (score 1):

Some hints: 1. As $\epsilon$ decreases to $0,$ we're taking the maximum of a smaller function over a smaller set; that's two bullets in your favor. 2. Note that

$$u(x) \le u_\epsilon(x) \le u(x) + \max_ {|y-x|\le \epsilon}|u(y)-u(x)| + \epsilon.$$

Comment: Thanks for your nice hints. Could you give me some hints on how to prove for fixed $\epsilon>0$, $u^{\epsilon}$ is continuous?