# On the sup convolution of upper semi continuous function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $f$ is a bounded upper semi continuous function on $[-1,1]$ and for any $\epsilon>0$, we define 
$$f^{\epsilon}(t):=\max\limits_{s\in[-1,1]}\left\{f(s)+\epsilon-\frac{1}{\epsilon}|t-s|^{2}\right\},\ \forall t\in[-1,1].$$
Can we prove that $f^{\epsilon}$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $[-1,1]$ as $\epsilon\rightarrow0$ or is there counterexample?

Answer (score 1):

The expression $ f(s)+\epsilon-\frac{1}{\epsilon}|t-s|^{2}$ is a Lipschitz function of $t$, with constant $4/\epsilon$. Taking the supremum over $s$ preserves this property. Hence, $f^\epsilon$ is a Lipschitz function, in particular continuous. And continuous functions cannot converge uniformly to $f$ unless $f$ is itself continuous.

Pointwise convergence holds, however (as was indicated [elsewhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1532637)).